Microsoft Graph API - createUploadSession
Resource not found for the segment 'root:' or invalid request when trying to create Upload Session. Token is connect and I am trying to upload large file from Databricks to SharePoint and that is why i need to create upload session. Here is the code

output_folder = "Databricks_Sharepoint_upload_test"
file_name = "test_file.csv"
input_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/sharepoint_input/test_file.csv"
request_body = {
'item': {
"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace",
'name': file_name,
"fileSize": os.path.getsize(input_path)
}
}
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}
response_upload_session = requests.post(f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{output_folder}:/{file_name}:/createUploadSession"', headers = headers, json = request_body)
print(response_upload_session.json())
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token

}
response_upload_session = requests.post(f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{output_folder}:/{file_name}:/createUploadSession"', headers = headers, json = request_body)
print(response_upload_session.json())
{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': "Resource not found for the segment 'root:'.", 'innerError': {'date': '2024-04-05T12:48:09', 'request-id': '', 'client-request-id': ''}}}

I have tried modifying both URL and request body , changing folder path and file name but it is always the same error at the end.

I would suggest to remove : after {output_folder}
/root:/{output_folder}:/{file_name}:/
response_upload_session = requests.post(f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{output_folder}/{file_name}:/createUploadSession"', headers = headers, json = request_body)


Well I still get an error just not bad request but invalid request
{'error': {'code': 'invalidRequest', 'message': 'Invalid request', 'innerError': {'date': '2024-04-05T13:17:56', 'request-id': '', 'client-request-id': ''}}}

I managed to fix invalid request error by removing 2 lines of code from request body and keeping only file_name and conflict behaviour, thank you
